# Storage of Variables Across iOS and WatchOS

Tags: watchkit

Is there any way to store a variable that can be accessed and changed by both the iOS and WatchOS applications? For example, a score set on one device, could be read, displayed and updated on the other. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Sharing Data section](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/SharingData.html) of Apple's App Programming Guide for watchOS.

If you want to share files, use a shared group container, but if you just want to share variables, which you only need at runtime, use the WatchConnectivity framework.